# WebRTC video streaming - javascript & python

Tags: websocket, server, webrtc, video-streaming, client

I have 4 clients (web pages) that contain video streams and I have to send all of them to server which will make some editing with openCV. After that, server should send all of video streams to one client that will show them with HTML video tag. I search on the Internet and see that I can do it with WebRTC and WebSockets. Does anyone have any idea, I am pretty new in this field?

First client.js (client that has video stream):

```js
// Config variables: change them to point to your own servers
const SIGNALING_SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:9999';
const TURN_SERVER_URL = 'localhost:3478';
const TURN_SERVER_USERNAME = 'username';
const TURN_SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 'credential';
// WebRTC config: you don't have to change this for the example to work
// If you are testing on localhost, you can just use PC_CONFIG = {}
const PC_CONFIG = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: 'turn:' + TURN_SERVER_URL + '?transport=tcp',
      username: TURN_SERVER_USERNAME,
      credential: TURN_SERVER_CREDENTIAL
    },
    {
      urls: 'turn:' + TURN_SERVER_URL + '?transport=udp',
      username: TURN_SERVER_USERNAME,
      credential: TURN_SERVER_CREDENTIAL
    }
  ]
};

// Signaling methods
let socket = io(SIGNALING_SERVER_URL, { autoConnect: false });

socket.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('Data received: ',data);
  handleSignalingData(data);
});

socket.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready');
  // Connection with signaling server is ready, and so is local stream
  createPeerConnection();
  sendOffer();
});

let sendData = (data) => {
  socket.emit('data', data);
};

// WebRTC methods
let pc;
let localStream;
let remoteStreamElement = document.querySelector('#remoteStream');

let getLocalStream = () => {
    let stream = document.getElementById('localStream').captureStream();
    localStream = stream;
    console.log('Stream found');

    socket.connect();
}

let createPeerConnection = () => {
  try {
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(PC_CONFIG);
    pc.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
    pc.ontrack = onTrack;
    pc.addStream(localStream);
    console.log('PeerConnection created');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('PeerConnection failed: ', error);
  }
};

let sendOffer = () => {
  console.log('Send offer');
  pc.createOffer().then(
    setAndSendLocalDescription,
    (error) => { console.error('Send offer failed: ', error); }
  );
};

let sendAnswer = () => {
  console.log('Send answer');
  pc.createAnswer().then(
    setAndSendLocalDescription,
    (error) => { console.error('Send answer failed: ', error); }
  );
};

let setAndSendLocalDescription = (sessionDescription) => {
  pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
  console.log('Local description set');
  sendData(sessionDescription);
};

let onIceCandidate = (event) => {
  if (event.candidate) {
    console.log('ICE candidate');
    sendData({
      type: 'candidate',
      candidate: event.candidate
    });
  }
};

let onTrack = (event) => {
  console.log('Add track');
  remoteStreamElement.srcObject = event.streams[0];
};

let handleSignalingData = (data) => {
  switch (data.type) {
    case 'offer':
      createPeerConnection();
      pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data));
      sendAnswer();
      break;
    case 'answer':
      pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data));
      break;
    case 'candidate':
      pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.candidate));
      break;
  }
};

function onInputFileChange() {
  var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
  console.log(file);
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  console.log(url);
  document.getElementById("localStream").src = url;

  getLocalStream();
}
```

Second client.js (client that should show video stream from first client):

```js
// Config variables: change them to point to your own servers
const SIGNALING_SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:9999';
const TURN_SERVER_URL = 'localhost:3478';
const TURN_SERVER_USERNAME = 'username';
const TURN_SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 'credential';
// WebRTC config: you don't have to change this for the example to work
// If you are testing on localhost, you can just use PC_CONFIG = {}
const PC_CONFIG = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: 'turn:' + TURN_SERVER_URL + '?transport=tcp',
      username: TURN_SERVER_USERNAME,
      credential: TURN_SERVER_CREDENTIAL
    },
    {
      urls: 'turn:' + TURN_SERVER_URL + '?transport=udp',
      username: TURN_SERVER_USERNAME,
      credential: TURN_SERVER_CREDENTIAL
    }
  ]
};

// Signaling methods
let socket = io(SIGNALING_SERVER_URL, { autoConnect: false });

socket.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('Data received: ',data);
  handleSignalingData(data);
});

socket.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready');
  // Connection with signaling server is ready, and so is local stream
  createPeerConnection();
  sendOffer();
});

let sendData = (data) => {
  socket.emit('data', data);
};

// WebRTC methods
let pc;
let localStream;
let remoteStreamElement = document.querySelector('#remoteStream');

let getLocalStream = () => {
  socket.connect();
}

let createPeerConnection = () => {
  try {
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(PC_CONFIG);
    pc.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
    pc.ontrack = onTrack;
    pc.addStream(localStream);
    console.log('PeerConnection created');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('PeerConnection failed: ', error);
  }
};

let sendOffer = () => {
  console.log('Send offer');
  pc.createOffer().then(
    setAndSendLocalDescription,
    (error) => { console.error('Send offer failed: ', error); }
  );
};

let sendAnswer = () => {
  console.log('Send answer');
  pc.createAnswer().then(
    setAndSendLocalDescription,
    (error) => { console.error('Send answer failed: ', error); }
  );
};

let setAndSendLocalDescription = (sessionDescription) => {
  pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
  console.log('Local description set');
  sendData(sessionDescription);
};

let onIceCandidate = (event) => {
  if (event.candidate) {
    console.log('ICE candidate');
    sendData({
      type: 'candidate',
      candidate: event.candidate
    });
  }
};

let onTrack = (event) => {
  console.log('Add track');
  remoteStreamElement.srcObject = event.streams[0];
};

let handleSignalingData = (data) => {
  switch (data.type) {
    case 'offer':
      createPeerConnection();
      pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data));
      sendAnswer();
      break;
    case 'answer':
      pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data));
      break;
    case 'candidate':
      pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.candidate));
      break;
  }
};

// Start connection
getLocalStream();
```

Server.py (signalling server):

```js
from aiohttp import web
import socketio

ROOM = 'room'

sio = socketio.AsyncServer(cors_allowed_origins='*', ping_timeout=35)
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)


@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ):
    print('Connected', sid)
    await sio.emit('ready', room=ROOM, skip_sid=sid)
    sio.enter_room(sid, ROOM)


@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):
    sio.leave_room(sid, ROOM)
    print('Disconnected', sid)


@sio.event
async def data(sid, data):
    print('Message from {}: {}'.format(sid, data))
    await sio.emit('data', data, room=ROOM, skip_sid=sid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app, port=9999)
```

Currently first client (peer) send video stream to second client (peer), but I want to add one more peer (in python) between them where I can make some video editing with OpenCV.